# QGIS: sewer system symbology

Tags: symbology, network, pipe-network

Is there any symbology set out there for sewer systems or other piped networks? The sort of elements I need to represent are:

- Conduits
- Junctions
- Pumps
- Weirs
- Outfalls
- Gates
- etc...

There are few sets for transport systems in the public domain, but I am yet to find one for this kind of networks.

Answer (score 3):

I have been searching within the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com) open source icon library and found some useful images. Some of these may work better than others when resized for mapping. They are all under a Creative Commons licence.

## Outfall

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=waste+water&i=125135)

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/outfall/25100/)

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/outfall/25099/)

## Drain

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/drain/104242/)

## Sewer

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/sewer/13479/)

## Manhole

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/manhole/26897/)

## Storage Tank

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/water-tank/173862/)

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/water-tank/173862/)

## Gate

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/aperture/17266/)

[image] [Get the SVG](https://thenounproject.com/term/aperture/16589/)